# How to remove "defer" attribute from output script in vue3 config (vue-cli 5)

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, vue-cli

Surprisingly I can't find any explanation "how to remove 'defer' attribute from output in vue3 configuration".

I don't want that `defer` definition in my output html script injection.

```
<script defer="defer" src="/app.js"></script>
```

expected result is:

```
<script src="/app.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to do it? I'm pretty sure there is a way but where it is?